# How to import website created through Azure Portal into TFS project?

Tags: azure, tfs

I created a website in the Azure portal, but now I can't find out how to import this into a TFS project. I have visual studio 2013. They seem completely disconnected in terms of importing a project from what the Azure portal creates. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jerelo - the way you solve your issue depends what type of website you deployed and how it was deployed originally.  Many of the pre-baked Website images for items like Drupal or Wordpess are not designed to be imported into TFS and auto-deployed.

You would need to download your files via FTP (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2014/08/02/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-upload-download-files.aspx) and then setup source-control deployments by selecting the "Set up deployment from source control" option in the Portal.

Visual Studio Online is the only TFS source you'll be able to use right now, otherwise you have Dropbox, Git or Mercurial deployments  Detailed options are listed here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/web-sites-deploy.md

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's a good overview. I later discovered I could use the azure portal to create a zip file of this MVC web site, and then I expanded it into the local source directory for TFS in VS. But, there was no solution file!

Seems like a missing link, that TFS can't see into an azure store. Anyway, thanks again.